# tmux command to move pane to edge of window?

Tags: tmux

In Vim, you can move a window to an edge of the viewport with H/J/K/L. Vim will make sure the window occupies the whole edge and resize/shift the other windows around it. Is there something similar for tmux? move-pane doesn't seem to have an option to preserve sizes like Vim does for you. rotate-pane is not the same behavior either and does not guarantee the pane will find the correct edge.

Answer (score 2):

I can think a couple of ways of achieving this, but I don't think they are exactly what you are after:

`(ctrl+b)` = the default trigger/shortcut.

One option is to use `(ctrl+b) + {` for moving left, or `(ctrl+b) + }` for moving right, this moves the content from one pane to another, while using `(ctrl+b) + space` to rearrange the panes in different layouts.

You could use `select-layout` to "shortcut" the wanted layout if you don't want to browse through all of them, for example `(ctrl+b) + (alt+#)` where **#** is a number between 1 and 5. You could also zoom in a pane with `(ctrl+b) + z` maybe to help.

I don't think you have a ***simple shortcut*** option to ***"move the pane around the window and resize the remaining panes accordingly"*** if that's exactly what you are looking for.